# jQuery create select and set value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that takes an array that is parsed to it, and then loops through to create one table row per dataset in the array, with the table rows having three cells - one text input and two selects. The same function should also set the two select values using the data that it receives, but this is my problem as it is not happening properly.

Here is the entire function:

```
function editVehicleServiceHistory(serviceHistory){

    var rows = serviceHistory;
    for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){  

    var setLocation = rows[i].sh_location;
    var setDateFrom = rows[i].sh_location_from;
    var setDateTo = rows[i].sh_location_to;

    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="location-edit-input-size" name="location' + counter + '" value="'+ setLocation +'"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><select name="date_from_select_edit" id="date_from_select_edit"><option value="Unknown">Unknown</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option></select></td>';

    $('#date_from_select_edit').val(setDateFrom);

   cols += '<td><select name="date_to_select_edit" id="date_to_select_edit"><option value="Present">Present</option><option value="Unknown">Unknown</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option></select></td>';
    $('#date_to_select_edit').val(setDateTo);

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);

    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

    counter++;

    }

  }
```

What is happening is this, if there are two sets of data that create two table rows then the end result should be:

**Text Input | Select | Select**
Melbourne | 2001 | 2008
Ballarat | 2008 | Present

Instead it looks like this:
Melbourne | 2008 | Present 
Ballarat | Unknown | Present

It suggests to me that as the function loops around for the second time (or subsequent time after that), the next array's values are overwriting the first table row rather than being correctly inserted into the second. So I'm ending up with the first table row having elements of the second tale row in it which is not what I'm after.

I think it might be happening because currently there are two selects in that table with the same name and id, but I'm not sure how I can make them unique values as my current attempts at integrating the counter (as seen in the location name text input) haven't worked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. you can't have duplicate IDs. 2) You're setting the value of select even before it's available in the DOM

Comment: Thank you for your help, Sicnarf111 helped me correct the ids issue but you were right in the setting of the value before the DOM, I moved those two lines of code below the append and it works perfectly now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct that the problem is with the ID's.

```
 $('#date_to_select_edit').val(setDateTo);
```

That line will only return the first element with the ID 'date_to_select_edit' that it finds. To give them unique ID's, just append the loop index to the end of it. like so:

```
<select name="date_from_select_edit' + i + '" id="date_from_select_edit' + i + '">
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there with the counter. (it seems you increment it at the end of the loop, and then reset it again at the beginning of the next iteration). I don't think you'll need the counter anyway though. Your loop variable 'i' should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days now (and getting very frustrated by it!) but at long last it works! Ishettyl also pointed out that where I was setting the select values was in the wrong place so I moved that to but everything functions exactly as planned.

The counter variable was a hold over from another operation it could do that I had disabled, but you're right it does nothing in this case so I have removed it.